# Persist FileUpload Control Value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have asp.net FileUpload control inside an update panel. When I click upload button, I am reading the file for some code, if code not found then I am showing ModalPopup for selecting a user from dropdown, otherwise uploading and emailing the file to user of that Code(this code is saved in Database).
If code not found,its displaying ModalPopup and removing the selected file, I want to persist the selected file after post back.
This is my code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"  />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFileupload" ValidationGroup="validate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* required" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and on Button Click

```
protected void btnupload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Reading the file and Checking from Database
    if(codefound)
    {
        //Sending email to the user of the Code
    }
    else
    {
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
    }
}
```

How can I persists  the value of Upload control on post back?

Comment: Consider (arguably more simple) suggestion in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111428/how-to-prevent-fileupload-control-from-clearing-on-postback to restructure the flow so that the only postback is done when you want to submit the file, and do any other manipulation with client side scripting

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Background:**:
When a file is selected using [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload.aspx) Control ,then on postback,  [PostedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile.aspx) property gets initialized with [HttpPostedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx) object for the file. Since http request cannot maintain state, so it looses it's state.

**NOTE:** FileUpload control will not work with asynchronous  postback.So a postback is needed to get the file. One way is to set the triggers for your Upload button, i.e. `<asp:PostBackTrigger >` & NOT `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>`

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploadImage" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
      <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload Image" 
           OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
      </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
          <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload"  />
      </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And your Upload button code:

```
 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        if (fileUpload1.HasFile)
        {                
            fileName = fileupload1.FileName;
            fileUpload1.SaveAs("~/UploadedContent/" + fileName);
        }
     }
```

**TO PERSIST THE VALUE OF FILEUPLOAD CONTROL**, you can store the `fileupload` object altogether  in session and after postback retrieve the values you require from session.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // store the FileUpload object in Session. 
        // "FileUpload1" is the ID of your FileUpload control
        // This condition occurs for first time you upload a file
         if (Session["FileUpload1"] == null && FileUpload1.HasFile)  
           { 
            Session["FileUpload1"] = FileUpload1; 
            Label1.Text = FileUpload1.FileName; // get the name 
           }
        // This condition will occur on next postbacks        
        else if (Session["FileUpload1"] != null && (! FileUpload1.HasFile)) 
          { 
            FileUpload1 = (FileUpload) Session["FileUpload1"]; 
            Label1.Text = FileUpload1.FileName; 
          } 
     //  when Session will have File but user want to change the file 
     // i.e. wants to upload a new file using same FileUpload control
     // so update the session to have the newly uploaded file
        else if (FileUpload1.HasFile) 
         { 
            Session["FileUpload1"] = FileUpload1; 
            Label1.Text = FileUpload1.FileName; 
         }
     }
```

Comment: Here 2nd part of above answer actually answers your questio: How to persist FileUpload Control vale. The first part just shows how to make FileUpload control work inside UpdatePanel. Since you didn't mentioned any issue with this, I hope this part is working already for you.

Comment: I tried doing this and received an error that the fileupload object is non-serializable and that it can not be stored in session.

Comment: it may be possible that SessionMode is set to SQLServer or StateServer , Can you try change it to InProc and see if its works ?

Answer (score 4):

This problem is somewhat well documented, the update panel is listed as not working with certain controls.

File upload, and tree view being 2 of the biggies.

To make it work you should use Triggers/PostbackTrigger

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" >
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"  />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFileupload" ValidationGroup="validate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* required" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" />
    <asp:Buton ID="btnupload" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="btnupload_Click"></asp:Button>
  </ContentTemplate>

  <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger   ControlID="btnupload"/>
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Could you explain how to use it with Triggers/Postback Trigger?

Comment: Please see modified answer.

Answer (score -1):

try add

```
$('form').attr('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
```