# position of control is changed after asynchronous postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, updatepanel

i have a panel within an update panel in my page
visible of panel is false by default and after asynchronous postback changes to true
my problem is after postback location of panel change to top of page
here is my code

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_caption_upload" Text="caption" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_caption_upload" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="radio_view_upload" OnSelectedIndexChanged="radio_view_upload_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
   <asp:ListItem text="custom"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem text="public"></asp:ListItem></asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="radio_view_upload" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="placeholder_panel" Visible="false" CssClass="hide">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_genre_upload" Text="genre" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="check_genre_upload" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="ID" RepeatColumns="7" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" DataSourceID="datasource_genre_upload"></asp:CheckBoxList>
                                <asp:LinqDataSource ID="datasource_genre_upload" runat="server" ContextTypeName="Video_Hosting.L2SDataContext" EntityTypeName="" Select="new (Title, ID)" TableName="Genres" OrderBy="ID">
                                </asp:LinqDataSource>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and here is code for slectedindex change

```
protected void radio_view_upload_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        if (radio_view_upload.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            placeholder_panel.Visible = true;
        } 
        else
        {
            placeholder_panel.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

after postback location of panel change to before first label

thanks for all of your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
if (radio_view_upload.SelectedIndex == 2)
```

Your `radio_view_upload` RadioButtonList only has 2 choices, so your if-statement will always go to the Else part. Only SelectedIndex 0 and 1 are available.

In most programming languages the first item in an array, collection, list etc will have 0 as starting index.

You could also use `if (radio_view_upload.SelectedValue == "myValue")`, but for this to work you have to add a `value="myValue"` to the ListItems.

**UPDATE**

Inside `<ContentTemplate>` you have a `<tr> <td>` and a `</td> </tr>` without matching `<table> </table>` tags. Maybe those tags are outside the UpdatePanel and not visible in your snippet. You should add/move those inside the UpdatePanel.

**UPDATE 2**

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_caption_upload" Text="caption" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_caption_upload" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="radio_view_upload" OnSelectedIndexChanged="radio_view_upload_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Text="custom"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="public"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <br />

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="radio_view_upload" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="placeholder_panel" Visible="true" CssClass="hide">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_genre_upload" Text="genre" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="check_genre_upload" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="ID" RepeatColumns="7" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"></asp:CheckBoxList>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not my problem.  .. My problem is changing location of panel ... Visiblity of panel is changed to true but location of it change to top of page

Comment: Thanks again i remove those tag but same problem ... When full postback occured location is true but in asynchronous postback location is changed ... I have a fileupload control that after full postback loose its file ... Only way to keep file is asynchronous postback... Session is not good idea for keep file

Comment: I tested your code and it all works as it should with those 2 fixes I mentioned. The only thing i cannot test is the content of `datasource_genre_upload`. Maybe there is something in there that causes the problem. Could you post (part of) the content of datasource_genre_upload?

Comment: Yeah datasource contain genre of movies like comedy etc

Comment: And you cannot prevent the FileUpload from losing the file after a full postback. You have to store the file server side if you want to keep it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18656681/5836671

Comment: No no no i save uploaded file after botton upload click ... But before save file i want to have some details about file like genre etc ... This require postback that cause loosing value of fileupload

Comment: I sort know what you mean. But that is possible by using your snippet. I've edited it a litte. But the filename is preserved when `radio_view_upload` is changed.

Comment: Solved i used table tag in my page i change all table, tr and td tags to asp: table tags and problem solved

Comment: Good to hear. Happy programming!