# How to store and retrieve asp:fileupload from session in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My program has an asp:FileUpload control that a user will select a file with. There is a button on the page that the users can click to do some data manipulation. When that button is clicked, the asp:fileUpload control looses the file the user has chosen.

I have found code that apparently works for C# programs, but as I am coding in VB.NET, I tried converting that code.

This is the C# code I used in the converter:

```
    if (Session["FileUpload1"] == null && FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        Session["FileUpload1"] = FileUpload1;
        lblFilename.Visible = true;
        lblFilename.Text = FileUpload1.FileName;
    }
    else if (Session["FileUpload1"] != null && (!FileUpload1.HasFile))
    {
        FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)Session["FileUpload1"];
        lblFilename.Visible = true;
        lblFilename.Text = FileUpload1.FileName;
    }
    else if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        Session["FileUpload1"] = FileUpload1;
        lblFilename.Visible = true;
        lblFilename.Text = FileUpload1.FileName;
    }
```

This is what the converter gave me as a VB result:

```
    If Session("FileUpload1") Is Nothing AndAlso FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        Session("FileUpload1") = FileUpload1
        lblFilename.Visible = True
        lblFilename.Text = FileUpload1.FileName
    ElseIf Session("FileUpload1") IsNot Nothing AndAlso (Not FileUpload1.HasFile) Then
        FileUpload1 = CType(Session("FileUpload1"), FileUpload)
        lblFilename.Visible = True
        lblFilename.Text = FileUpload1.FileName
    ElseIf FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        Session("FileUpload1") = FileUpload1
        lblFilename.Visible = True
        lblFilename.Text = FileUpload1.FileName
    End If
```

This is what I changed it to in order to use it for my program:

```
    If Session("fileuPreCalImage") Is Nothing AndAlso fileuPreCalImage.HasFile Then
        Session.Add("fileuPreCalImage", fileuPreCalImage)
    ElseIf Session("fileuPreCalImage") IsNot Nothing AndAlso (Not fileuPreCalImage.HasFile) Then
        fileuPreCalImage = CType(Session("fileuPreCalImage"), FileUpload)
    ElseIf fileuPreCalImage.HasFile Then
        Session("fileuPreCalImage") = fileuPreCalImage
    End If
```

The code doesn't compile because of an error, in the 4th line of my code, that says: "Value of type 'FileUpload' cannot be converted to 'FileUpload'.

Is there a way I can do this in VB.NET to maintain the FileUpload file after a button click?

Edit:  I took the C# code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18656681/5265207

Answer (score 1):

Replace----

```
fileuPreCalImage = CType(Session("fileuPreCalImage"), FileUpload)
```

By------

```
fileuPreCalImage =  DirectCast(Session("fileuPreCalImage"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload)
```

Comment: What that replace will do? A new issue? Explain your answer.